# I need to add an element after the root and one element after the root

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to add an element after the root element of an XML, but I can't really achieve that.

This is what I got so far with XSL.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="topNode" select="name(/*)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{$topNode}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I have to start with.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order_status xmlns="myNameSpace">
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
    </row>
</order_status>
```

This is the goal.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<order_status xmlns="myNameSpace">
    <order_status>
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
        </row>
    </order_status>
</order_status>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `xsl:element` then you need to specify the namespace of your "top node" too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="topNode" select="name(/*)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="topNodeNamespace" select="namespace-uri(/*)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{$topNode}" namespace="{$topNodeNamespace}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, change the template to match the root element instead, and use `xsl:copy` to create an extra copy (as that will copy the namespace too)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I actually have one issue:
My root contains a prefix that I want to remove from the next element
<ns:order_status xmlns:ns="http://namespace">
 <row>

What I'm getting is:
<ns:order_status xmlns:ns="http://namespace"><ns:sap_order_status>

Is it possible to remove the prefix from the element?

Comment: I think you should probably ask a new question here, now that this answer has been accepted. Note that semantically, there is no difference between `<ns:order_status xmlns:ns="namespace">` and `<order_status xmlns="namespace">`.